# Retrieve bit value from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I am trying to fetch bit value from database it gives an error. The following code is given below:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISADMIN FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE USER_NAME=@User AND ISPASSWORD=@Pass", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", cbUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pass", txtPassword.Text);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

b = (bool)dr["ISADMIN"];//*Here it gives error
```

Error:

> *Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.*

Comment: are you certain that data being is returned?

Comment: Did you really think your problem was because of attempting to retrieve a bit? If so, then you should probably have tried retrieving an `int` first.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) on the data reader first.

```
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(dr.Read())
    {
         //now read the value(s)
    }
}
```

If you are certain there is going to be exactly one result,
using [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) would be a better approach:

```
b = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thank u .... but when I am going by your choice it is giving another problem.

Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

You Have to Call Read Method of SqldataReader.

```
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while(dr.Read())
 {
 b = (bool)dr["ISADMIN"];
 }
```

Comment: Thank u.... But going by your process it is giving an error

"Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: what is data type of ISADMIN in database?

Comment: @KumarSaurav This Error can occured because it may be returning null value from database,check it.

Comment: when i execute the query in sql it is showing values but return value is null. how to get the value then?

Comment: What Value you are getting?, it should be in True Or False

Comment: The value I am getting is in True or False but the return value is 0.